# How to get single dimensional array from two dimensional array in php/laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am doing laravel project. I have one sql query as,

```
$catcount=2;
    for($i=0;$i<$catcount;$i++) {
        $subCat[] = Category::where('parent_id', '=', $userCategory[$i])->pluck('id');
    }
```

$subCat returns an array as,

```
[[54,55,56,57,58],[48,49,50,51,52]]
```

I want this array as a single dimensional array like,

```
[54,55,56,57,58,48,49,50,51,52]
```

I am not getting how to do this, Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: `array_merge($subCat[0],$subCat[1])`

Comment: what if count is more than 2

Comment: in that case, check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448162/how-to-get-single-dimensional-array-from-two-dimensional-array-in-php-laravel/36449487#36449487)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest You to do ids merge before querying, so You will save some run time by accessing database only one time.

```
    $catcount    = 2;
    $parents_ids = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $catcount; $i++) {
        $parents_ids[] = $userCategory[$i];
    }
    $subCats = Category::whereIn('parent_id', $parents_ids)->pluck('id');
```

Comment: Thanks, I got what I exactly wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$catcount=2;
for($i=0;$i<$catcount;$i++) {
   $subCat[] = Category::where('parent_id', '=' $userCategory[$i])->pluck('id');
}

array_merge($subCat[0],$subCat[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but what if I got count as 3 or 4,etc

Answer (score 0):

From your final array, you can just do an array merge

```
list($a1, $a2) = $subCat;
$subCat = array_merge($a1, $a2);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do that. One of them: simple, but universal, readable and updatable (if something will change in your data structure, you'll be able to update this code in no time):

```
$newArr = [];
foreach ($subCat as $subArr) {
    foreach ($subArr as $value) {
        $newArr[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your array have multiple elements, you can merge them using this code:

```
$subCats = call_user_func_array("array_merge", $subCat);
```